# Get Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) using Requests, Urllib and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, urllib2, windows-server

Trying to call a URL and get an HTML table from an internal server on network.

When entering a URL into a browser, the page and table load.

When calling URL in Python using Requests, URLLIB, and Pandas, a Network Error (`dns_unresolved_hostname`) is returned.

I have updated the hosts file to include Localhost. I unchecked "Don't use proxy server for local addresses". I can ping the server and it replies. I have changed the server name to the IP address and tried removing the port in the URL. No idea here.

```
import requests 
r = requests.get('http://fc12rp01:8000/bin/ReportCall.py?rule=N2') 
print(r.content)
```

Returns:

```
<HTML><HEAD>...........<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)
```

Proxy Settings:

[image: Proxy Settings]

Host file settings:

[image: Host file settings]

Comment: Please provide the code and URL.

Comment: did you add `fc12rp01` to `hosts` as  `ip_address fc12rp01` ? Did you test `ping fc12rp01` or `ping localhost`?

Comment: Can you print `r.url`?

Comment: @furas, yes can ping both local host and fc12rp01, also added to host file.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg yes, returns http://fc12rp01:8000/bin/ReportCall.py?rule=N2

Comment: it looks like problem has server, not your code. If your code would have problem with resolving name then it would raise error. OR server expects something more in request. maybe it needs correct header `User-Agent`.